# changing figure title and saving doesn't save new title

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a lot of plots that I wish to save to a directory. I need to change the title of each figure though. This I can do fine with the code below.

```
        lbl = ['abc'];
        tag = ['res_0_VW'];      % there is some logic to determine this tag but not relevant to this post

        hfigs = get(0, 'children');
        for m = 1 : length(hfigs(:, 1))
            if m == 2
                h = get(gca, 'Title');
                t = get(h, 'String');
                t = [t ' ' lbl ' ' tag];
                title(t);
            end
            saveas(hfigs(m), [dir_check '\fig_' tag num2str(hfigs(m)) '.fig'])         
        end
```

The figure saves correctly in my directory however the title which gets updated by my code above is not there when I open the figure, why?

**update**

when I stop the code after the title has been changed and save it manually it works, in that when I open the figure I can see the title with the adjustment

**2nd update**

I'm thinking I might have to update the handle before saving although not sure how to do this?

Comment: Try `drawnow` command right before the save procedure and let me know whether it helps.

Comment: no sadly makes no difference]

Comment: What happens when you use `set(get(gca,'Title'),'String',t)` instead of `tittle(t)`? Both with and without `drawnow`? You can alos use `get(get(gca,'title'),'string')` to retrieve title string :)

Comment: Does `refresh` command help?

Comment: tried all of those suggestions but still not saving the changes to the title

Comment: Can you identify the handle to the axes you want to change their title? then replace the `gca` pointer by this pointer. It may be element of `hfigs`. If you know the pointer `linePointer` of the line inside the axes, you can use `ax=get(linePointer,'parent')`. Or try to define axes `ax=axes()` and then try to `set(get(ax,'title'...` or `title(ax,t)`.

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have been clearer, I'm trying to change the chart title not any of the axis titles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112194/discussion-between-crowley-and-mhelpme).

Comment: You are only changing the title on m==2, are you checking that one?

Comment: yes I'm checking the figure on m==2